# Assertion Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java EE project with some tests , however when I type a xhtml or jsp file the following error occurs:

[image]

All the time that I typed this files the error appear.
I tried disable the errors validations in eclipse for jsp and xhtml validations, but it persists.
My Eclipse is Luna 4.4.1. Has anyone have any idea?

Comment: Your error message is not visible.

Comment: Check your log file in `workspace/.metadata` and see if there is a corresponding stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I parcial resolve this problems when I change the default web page editor to html editor in eclipse ... 
The tags libs are like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
      <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      template="/template/default.xhtml">
```

So when I move to a normal `<html>` with this same tag libs , the errors do not occurs..  So the solution for now is using a HTML editor ... thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using an older version of Eclipse. Eclipse Kepler works fine on this project, The edition to Xhtml and JSP pages are ok.